# How do you Add a Library folder to eclipse?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Okay, I know this is a Noob question but I cant see to get it figured out! I'm trying to get the Android-ViewPageIndicater library imported to Eclipse, but it doesn't have a LIB file to add, and I cant figure out how to import the library folder because Eclipse says theres no project in it! Does anyone know how to do this? Thanks

Comment: IMHO, you need to add it as a source.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was facing the same issue. The solution is

1>Create a new android project with existing source (Select that library folder)

2> Mark that project as library

Later you can use this library for other projects

Comment: What if the Library Project doesn't have AndroidManifest file?

Comment: `Right Click Library Project->Properties->Android->check mark Is Library -> Apply`

Comment: @WilliamL.Right click of project -> select properties -> click on Android -> add your library as reference