# Zoom imageview and coordinates

Tags: android, imageview, zooming, coordinate

I'm trying to develope an application able to zoom with two fingers an imageview, i've read a lot of comments on this web but i 'm not able to make it run, I need to get the coordinates X Y after zoom too, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Chris Bane's `PhotoView` library. https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView

It also has built-in functions regarding to getting the coordinates when user make an interaction.

Comment: Thank you but i'm trying to import the library and appears a lot of errors, can you explain me how must i do it?

Comment: Actually there is a sample Application in there. You can go with that. Basicly you have to add it as an Android project in your eclipse. And in your app settings in eclipse you should add this project as a library into your app. And then you can access PhotoView object.

Comment: But there are two folders, library and sample, ¿which i must import as an Android project?¿Both? And in app settings i import the library and error again...I don't know how to import library in folder

Comment: You should import both of them. You will use library one in your project. The sample one also use library to do the work. You can see how the library is used in the sample. And lastly adding library as a project described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11150327/how-do-you-add-a-library-folder-to-eclipse